# PHP: Why is this image compression method rotating my image by 90 degrees?

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have a PHP image method to compress the and resize the images on the server before inserting them into the Database, however all portrait images turn into landscape, and landscape turn into portrait.  What is causing this too happen?

The method is defined as:

```
private static function fit_image_file_to_width($file, $w, $mime = 'image/jpeg') {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);
    $newwidth = $w;
    $newheight = $w * $height / $width;

    switch ($mime) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
        case 'image/png';
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            break;
        case 'image/bmp';
            $src = imagecreatefromwbmp($file);
            break;
        case 'image/gif';
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            break;
    }

    $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
    imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

    switch ($mime) {
        case 'image/jpeg':
            imagejpeg($dst, $file);
            break;
        case 'image/png';
            imagealphablending($dst, false);
            imagesavealpha($dst, true);
            imagepng($dst, $file);
            break;
        case 'image/bmp';
            imagewbmp($dst, $file);
            break;
        case 'image/gif';
            imagegif($dst, $file);
            break;
    }

    imagedestroy($dst);
}
```

And I call it like this:

```
self::fit_image_file_to_width($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 1080, $_FILES["file"]["type"]);
$flag = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $imageURL);
```

The upload works fine, just the orientation of the image is wrong.

Comment: What is the source of your images ? I already seen this happening with images taken with my phone. Modifying my images removed the image's metadata that included the phone's orientation. Maybe it is related.

Comment: Hi Mat, I think that may be the case, uploading through Postman will maintain the images orientation, but when I upload to my API via iPhone thats where I see this problem occurring.  Any way of solving this server side?

Comment: In my case I had to read the EXIF metadata (I don't remember which field) and depending on its value, add a rotation command somewhere in the PHP routine. You may try [exif_read_data function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php). The orientation tag is described here http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html

Comment: I just did this on my end, great minds think alike! thanks Mat

Comment: Extra reading material: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php#112902